# How to put round Buttons next to an Include

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-button

I have created small rounded buttons and trying to put them right next to an include but I can't seem to get the round buttons next to the include. I can only get the rounded buttons above the include.

What I have gotten

[image: Current]

What I would like to achieve

[image: What I need to achieve]

**activty_mediation_tracker.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBlack"
tools:context="com.richard.worktracker.MeditationTrackerActivity">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/topBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/acton_bar_imageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"

        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_app_icon" />

    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topBar"
    tools:context="com.richard.worktracker.MeditationTrackerActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGuru"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="GURU"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="143dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="5dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnLearn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="LEARN" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnPower"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="POWER" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".75"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"

                        android:text="30 Day Ave"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorGolden"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:text="DAILY MUST"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <!--<include-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/activity_item_money"-->
                <!--layout="@layout/money_activity_item" />-->

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnMediateLevel1"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                   />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnMediateLevel2"
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btnMediateLevel3"
                        android:layout_width="10dp"
                        android:layout_height="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
                       />

                </LinearLayout>

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/activity_item_meditate"
                        layout="@layout/meditation_activity_item"
                        />

                    <include
                        android:id="@+id/activity_item_exercise"
                        layout="@layout/exercise_activity_item" />



                <!--<include-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/activity_item_study"-->
                <!--layout="@layout/study_activity_item" />-->

                <!--<include-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/activity_item_crush"-->
                <!--layout="@layout/crush_activity_item" />-->

                <!--<include-->
                <!--android:id="@+id/activity_item_create"-->
                <!--layout="@layout/create_activity_item" />-->

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/activity_item_fun"
                    layout="@layout/fun_activity_item" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_current_time"
                    android:layout_width="170dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Hello World!"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorGreen"
                    android:textSize="36dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/activity_item_work"
                    layout="@layout/work_activity_item" />

                <include
                    android:id="@+id/activity_item_other"
                    layout="@layout/other_activity_item" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAngel"
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:onClick="handleClick"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_bg_button"
                    android:text="Angel"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_timer_0"
                    style="@style/timer_button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/timer5_toggle_bg" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_timer_1"
                    style="@style/timer_button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/timer10_toggle_bg" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_timer_2"
                    style="@style/timer_button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/timer15_toggle_bg" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_timer_3"
                    style="@style/timer_button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/timer20_toggle_bg" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_timer_4"
                    style="@style/timer_button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/timer30_toggle_bg" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_timer_5"
                    style="@style/timer_button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/timer1h_toggle_bg" />

                <ToggleButton
                    android:id="@+id/button_timer_6"
                    style="@style/timer_button"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/timercustom_toggle_bg" />


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_details"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_bg_button"
                android:onClick="handleClick"
                android:text="@string/str_details"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"

                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button_about_us"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_bg_button"
                android:onClick="handleClick"
                android:text="@string/str_about_us"
                android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_Calculation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_bg_button"
            android:onClick="handleClick"
            android:text="Calculations"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**roundedbutton.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="#FF2A2A" />
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is include?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See you need to create a new **Linear layout** with **Orientaion "horizontal"** in which you will put the  those 3 dots layout and the **Meditaion Button**

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <include
            android:id="@+id/activity_item_meditate"
            layout="@layout/meditation_activity_item"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMediateLevel1"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMediateLevel2"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMediateLevel3"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have added the lines and it didn't move the buttons to the right.

Comment: please see above in the answer to see what I said and to show you what is happening. Thanks

Comment: these red dots are button? Can you tell me the name of those buttons

Comment: Yes they are buttons.The name of the three rounded buttons are btnMediateLevel1, btnMediateLevel2 and btnMediateLevel3

Comment: Can you tell me the name of those buttons

Comment: button names are btnMediateLevel1, btnMediateLevel2 and btnMediateLevel3

Comment: you want to show these button vertically to that meditate pray??

Comment: Yes that is what I would like to happen.

Comment: check the answer